# Looping through an array and delaying a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, setinterval, timedelay

I'm trying to continuously loop through an array of number values which will be passed to a setInterval function as the delay value that triggers another function.  Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<p>On</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timing = [5000, 10000, 17000, 8000, 14000, 9000, 12000, 8000, 20000, 7000, 13000, 7000, 17000, 8000, 13000, 12000, 18000]
    //function to change
    function change(){
            var p = $("p").html();
            if(p === "On"){
                $("p").html("Off"); 
            } else {
                $("p").html("On");
            }
        }


    function myFunction(){
        for (var i = 0; i < timing.length; i++){
            var switchTime = timing[i];

            setInterval(function(){
                change(); 

            },switchTime);

        }
    } myFunction();

});
```

I'd like to have the change function fire continuously at different delayed times.  Right now the timing doesn't seem to be correct when I run it.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please describe your expectations and the actual outcome.

Comment: According to the numbers in the timing array, I'm expecting the change function to fire continuously every 5, 10, 17, 8, 14 etc seconds.   The outcome right now is that the text within the p tag is changing, but not at those intervals.  I'm suspecting that my function is holding onto previous intervals.

Comment: This is what I meant - you are intervalling the same function over and over, so, of course you actually might have these intervals, but the impression is misleading.

Comment: Would it make sense to call clearInterval right after my setInterval in the loop to make sure that the change function is receiving the correct number?

Comment: Could work, give it a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, using a loop will not work, because a lot of `setInterval` (or `setTimeout()`) are "instantly" launched during a few microseconds.
So they do their job as stated by their own `timing[i]`, but from almost the same time!

At the opposite, you must launch each step *only when the previous one ends*.

Here is a working example (see also [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01hktLtv/)), where I added some visual tracking of the process:

HTML:

```
<p id="on-off">On</p>
<p id="delay"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timing = [
    5000, 10000, 17000, 8000, 14000, 9000, 12000, 8000, 20000, 7000, 13000,
    7000, 17000, 8000, 13000, 12000, 18000
  ];
  function myFunction(i){
    i |= 0;
    if (i < timing.length - 1) {
      var switchTime = timing[i]
          $onOff = $('#onOff');
      $('#delay').html('i=' + i + ', delay=' + switchTime);
      $onOff.html($onOff.html() == 'On' ? 'Off' : 'On');
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          myFunction(i + 1);
        }, switchTime
      )
    } else {
      $('#delay').html('end');
    }
  }
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely helpful!  Thanks so much for the explanation and fiddle.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just increment the variable `i` inside the `setInterval` function.

```
function myFunction(){
    for (var i = 0; i < timing.length; ){
        var switchTime = timing[i];

        setInterval(function(){
            change(); 
           i++;
        },switchTime);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` because you are doing this in a loop. `setInterval` will initialise a timer that continuously fires at the specified delay (e.g. if delay if 5sec, it will fire at 5, 10, 15 and so forth). By using `setTimeout` in your **iteration**, the timer only fires once per iteration after the specified delay and the next iteration initialises a new timer for the next delay value.

Comment: Right, I tried setTimeout as well, but can I continuously loop through the array using it?  Once the loop is over, I need it to start again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you might not be clearing old intervals as you call `setInterval`. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval you might need to clear previous intervals with `clearInterval`. Especially if you use the same method for all your intervals I think you might not get what you want. So:

1. Create an interval, save the current ID globally
2. When your callback being called, clear the current interval using `clearInterval` function
3. Repeat